# how to declare and create dictionary with object as key

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-5

I'm trying to create a typescript dictionary which its key is an object with 2 properties:

I've tried to use an interface for the key:

```
 /*
export interface IMyDictionary<TValue>
{
  [{ property1 : string, property2: number}] : TValue  //or 
  [IMyDictionaryKey] : TValue // none of them works
}
*/
export interface IMyDictionaryKey
{
   property1 : string;
   property2 : number
}

export class MyDictionaryKey implements IMyDictionaryKey
{
    property1 : string;
    property2 : number;
    constructor(prop1: string, prop2 : number)
    {
       property1 = prop1;
       property2 : prop2;
    }
}
```

in the component itself I would like to do something like:

```
Mydictionary : IMyDictionary<number[]>; //OR 
Mydictionary : {} = {};
```

and to set new key-value items:

```
this.Mydictionary[new MyDictionaryKey("AAAA", 1) as IMyDictionaryKey] = [];
```

and then insert array of values as a value to that key:

```
this.Mydictionary[{ property1: "AAAA", property2: 1}] = [1,2,3,4];
```

Comment: Object property names can only be strings in Javascript, so in Typescript as well.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich can be number as well {1: 1} is valid object

Comment: @JurajKocan: Only because JS translates the number to a string, x = {1: "A", "1": "B"} makes x an object with 1 element.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich x = {"1": "A", 1: "B"} makes x as {1: "B"}... i dont want to argue with you, just of interest

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a plain javascript object as dictionary use a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). A `Map` can use any object as a key: `new Map<IMyDictionaryKey, any>`. In particular, there is a [WeakMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap), which focuses on the use of objects as keys.